# How to get the COUNT of rows in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a data in database which gives me 8 rows based on date range out of which 5 are HCT, is there any formula in crystal report where I can get that count of those 'Abbr' ?

I am comparing HCT text from Dynamic report selection, I need to know can we create a variable which gives us count of 'Abbr'.
like for

1. HCT should return 5
2. US should return 2
3. RN should return 1 value.

[image]

**UPDATE 1:**

Here is what I am trying to do. I have secondary selection criteria as Dynamic report along with date range.
[image]

in the above example I have selected only "HCT", now even though sql data is returning 8 rows (HCT,US,RN) I need only the HCT count i.e. 5.

[image]
If I select "HCT" and "US" in the secondary criteria then I should get count of both HCT and US i.e. 5 + 2 = 7.
if I am not selecting anything then it should return 0, so irrespective of the data from DB, the value should be summed based on selection of my criteria.

am I clear enough?

Answer (score 1):

Use *Running Totals*.

Specifically, make a Distinct Count running total for each Date Range code. You can set a formula in the Running Total Wizard to only evaluate records where, for example, `{DateRange} = "HCT"`

Comment: I agree that we should use running totals, have shared my example under Update:1 check that is clear enough for thing I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Then you'll need to perform the total only when the `{DateRange}` value is in your Selected Values. Can you think of a formula that will return True when a string is inside a collection of other strings?

Comment: Date range is my first selection criteria then comes the dynamic report selection, so actual data shouldn't hinder with this secondary selection. I am not sure what you asking about string inside a collection.

Comment: Thankyou '4444' for your reply however I couldn't actually able to fix it based on your criteria, I got how to do it I have posted my answer.

Comment: @Manjuboyz You got remarkably close. You just needed to take the `{Command.GlobalSkillAbbr} in {?GlobalSkill}` from SumOfSkills and use that as the condition in the Running Total.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my question, I am just putting it here so that someone may help for the above mentioned formula.

**This is what I did**

Created a Formula(not running totals) by name **SumOfSkills**

```
if({Command.GlobalSkillAbbr} in {?GlobalSkill}) then 1 else 0
```

here Command.GlobalSkillAbbr is my "HCT" and '{?GlobalSkill} will contain all Global skills.

and used another formuala to sum it up.

```
Sum(SumOfSkills)
```

which gives me desired output.